# JAXB Marshall not output XML

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to create a simple JAXB program and write the object out to a xml file however its not creating any output - I am pasting sample code and output -

Code -

```
 ObjectFactory fct = new ObjectFactory();
        ImportParams imp = fct.createImportParams();
        FolderMaps fmaps = fct.createFolderMaps();

        FolderMap fmap = fct.createFolderMap();
        imp.setFolderMaps(fmaps);
        fmap.setSourceFolderPath("test");
        fmaps.getFolderMap().add(fmap);
        System.out.println("Size is " + fmaps.getFolderMap().size());
        System.out.println("Path is " + fmap.getSourceFolderPath());


        ImportParams imp1 = new ImportParams();
        imp1.setFolderMaps(fmaps);

JAXBContext ctx = null;
System.out.println("Writing JAXB objects");
try {
    ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.au");
    System.out.println("Inside JAXB");
    Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
    System.out.println("Marshal Started");
    marshaller.marshal(fmaps, System.out);
    marshaller.marshal(imp, System.out);
    marshaller.marshal(fmap, System.out);
    System.out.println("Marshal Completed");
    marshaller.marshal(fmaps, new File ("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\eclipse_workspace_64\\abcjaxb.xml"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Output is

```
Size is 1
Path is test
Writing JAXB objects
Inside JAXB
Marshal Started
Parameter file successfully created
```

Its terminating after marshal started and not creating the xml file

Comment: Can you add some logging ( like System.err.println(e) ) in the Exception block? Is there any error message displayed?

Comment: Here is the issue "Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "com.au.FolderMap" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation" , How to add the rootelement

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@XmlRootElement` to your `com.au.FolderMap` class, e.g.

```
 package com.au;
 @XmlRootElement
 public class FolderMap {
      // ...
 )
```

Comment: throwing an error Cannot resolve XML element declaration with namespace 'http:/test/oie/importControl/9' and name 'folderMaps' in this context

Comment: In one of my class ImportParams below is mention "@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://test/oie/importControl/9", name = "importParams")" so I am assuming importControl should be the root however when I am creating an object of Importparams its still giving me the same error

Comment: You need to actually post the classes you are trying to serailize/deserlialze and an example of the XML, else it's impossible to know where the problem lies. This sounds like something in the class to XML modelling, but not sure.

Comment: It worked , I have added the @XMLRootelement tag in the import class however when I tried to add with the name tag it was failing , so the issue is solved now